# TopHat could not find bowtie index files even though path is correct

Tags: bash, bioinformatics, sungridengine

I generated bowtie index files using bowtie-index in a bash script as follows:

```
bowtie-build $FA_FILE $OUTPUT_BASE
```

(script can be found here: https://github.com/kennethphough/bioinformatics/blob/master/sge/sge_build_index)

I want each node of my cluster to align my sequence files to a chromosome and not to the entire genome.  So in theory if I run an instance of tophat for each chromosome for the same sequence file on each node, it should be faster than running tophat on one node for the entire genome.

I made sure that the location of my bowtie index files was exported like so:

```
export BOWTIE_INDEXES="$(dirname ${EBWT})/"
```

and then execute tophat like so:

```
tophat -p 4 -G $GTF -o $OBASE $Chr $FASTQ
```

`$GTF` contains that path to the annotation file, `$Chr` contains the file name of the index file (excluding the file extension .ebwt) and `$FASTQ` contains the path to my sequence read file.

(script can be found here: https://github.com/kennethphough/bioinformatics/blob/master/sge/sge_tophat)

When I run the script I get an error saying bowtie index could not be foudn. Excerpt below:

```
[Sun Oct  5 15:08:48 2014] Beginning TopHat run (v1.1.2)
-----------------------------------------------
[Sun Oct  5 15:08:48 2014] Preparing output location /home/kennethphough/GSE58365/fast/chr11_gl000202_random.1/
[Sun Oct  5 15:08:48 2014] Checking for Bowtie index files
Error: Could not find Bowtie index files /home/kennethphough/genome/hg19/chr11_gl000202_random.1.*
```

The bowtie index file in question for the above error is `chr11_gl000202_random.1.ebwt` which I have confirmed that it's there.  Any lead on what's going wrong will be greatly appreciated.

Bowtie version is 0.12.7
Tophat version is 1.1.2

Comment: The links in your question are dead and thus useless for other users.

Comment: I'm glad you figured out your problems, but you should consider getting newest versions of these softwares...(i.e. bowtie is up to 1.1.1 and tophat is at 2.0.13)

Comment: Thanks for the advice.  I'll ask my admin if they can update the programs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that there is more than one file for a bowtie index.  So for the example above `chr11_gl000202_random` has:

```
chr11_gl000202_random.1.ebwt
chr11_gl000202_random.2.ebwt
chr11_gl000202_random.3.ebwt
chr11_gl000202_random.rev.1.ebwt
chr11_gl000202_random.rev.1.ebwt
```

so instead of passing on the file name without the extension I needed to get the chromosome sequence name like so:

```
Chr=`echo "$FNAME" | awk -F. '{print $1}'`
```

I've update my script at github to reflect the changes.